# Python: String manipulation issue when trying to form SQL statement

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following string:

```
query = '''UPDATE table1 SET 'variable1' = 'value1', 'something' = "['bla', 'yada']", location = 'chicago' WHERE id = 9'''
```

This is a string that I will be using as an argument to a custom library to update a SQLite table. What I need to do is remove the single quotes around the word before each equal sign (if the word does have single quotes).

Desired output is as follows:

```
query = '''UPDATE table1 SET variable1 = 'value1', something = "['bla', 'yada']", location = 'chicago' WHERE id = 9'''
```

Notice the single quotes around words 'variable1' and 'something' have been removed. How can I do this for all queries in this form?

Comment: What do you mean by "all queries in this form?"? Which `all` queries are you talking about here?

Comment: Sorry, meant all queries that follow a similar structure to the example provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to replace those. The regex captures the values inside the single quotes if they are followed by a space and equals sign, then replaces the quote and value with just the value.

```py
import re
query = '''UPDATE table1 SET 'variable1' = 'value1', 'something' = "['bla', 'yada']", location = 'chicago' WHERE id = 9'''

updated_query = re.sub(r"'([^']+)'(?=\s=)", r"\1", query)
print(query)
print(updated_query)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
UPDATE table1 SET 'variable1' = 'value1', 'something' = "['bla', 'yada']", location = 'chicago' WHERE id = 9
UPDATE table1 SET variable1 = 'value1', something = "['bla', 'yada']", location = 'chicago' WHERE id = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting the query with commas. To get all different fields.

```
fields = query.split(", ")
```

then splitting each field by an `=` sign

```
fields = [i.split("=") for i in fields]
```

then removing the single quotes but only from the left hand side of the assignment operator

```
for f in fields:
    f[0] = f[0].replace("'", "")
```

then just going backwards and combining the strings

```
fields = ["=".join(f) for f in fields]
query = ", ".join(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
words = query.split(" ")

new_query = ' '.join([words[i].replace("'", "") if words[i + 1] == '=' else words[i] for i in range(len(words) - 1)] + [words[len(words) - 1]])
```

Comment: This fails when there's a whitespace before the = sign.